# Add Column Sort Index To Column Headers For Multi Column Sort

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there anyway through a header template or anything else to put index markers into the column headers?  For example if I have a grid with a bunch a columns and the user clicks on the "Name" column and then the "City" column.

I would like to put a "1" next to "Name" and a "2" next to "City" to indicate the sort order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Headertemplates, there is an issue with not being able to capture the event for "just before column headers are rendered." I have the following `dataBinding` event that still does what you want :

```
 dataBinding: function(e){

    var sortArray = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sort();                
    if(sortArray)
    {
    for(var i = 0;i < sortArray.length; i++)
    {

     $("#grid th[data-field=" + sortArray[i].field + "] .k-link").html("(" + (i+1) + ")" + sortArray[i].field ); 
    }

      var sortedColumns = sortArray.map(function(o){return o.field});

      var columns = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns; 
     for (i in columns)
     {
        if(sortedColumns.indexOf(columns[i].field) == -1)
         $("#grid th[data-field=" + columns[i].field + "] .k-link").html(columns[i].field ); 
     }

    }

  }
```

The following is the Kendo dojo link : http://dojo.telerik.com/eneH/4

Comment: this is a great and clever solution!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution, similar to above

```js
 $('.field_sort_number').remove();
 var sort_v = gridDataSource.sort();
 if (sort_v)
   for (i = 0; i < sort_v.length; ++i) {
     $('th[data-field="' + sort_v[i].field + '"] a[class="k-link"]').append('<sub class="field_sort_number">' + (i + 1) + '</sub>');
   }
```